# memset против обнуления через простой цикл

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, что это за особенность такая странная?

Вот простенький код: VS2019, x64, release.

-0.Создаю вектор, заполняю его рандомными значениями.

-1.Создаю указатель и выделяю память через malloc, память не инициализирую  и через цикл копирую данные из вектора в выделенную память.

-2.Создаю указатель и выделяю память через malloc, инициализирую выделенную память 0 через Memset и через цикл копирую данные из вектора в выделенную память.

-3.Создаю указатель и выделяю память через malloc, инициализирую выделенную память 1 через Memset и через цикл копирую данные из вектора в выделенную память.

-4.Создаю указатель и выделяю память через malloc, инициализирую выделенную память 0через Цикл и через цикл копирую данные из вектора в выделенную память.

-5.Создаю указатель и выделяю память через malloc, инициализирую выделенную память 1 через Цикл и через цикл копирую данные из вектора в выделенную память.

А теперь меряю время каждой секции с 1 по 5:

1: 31 мс

2: 33 мс

3: 33 мс

4: 32 мс

5: 12 мс

То есть все вариант заполнения память кроме п.5 имеют одинаковое время и только п.5 - где память инициализируется через цикл и единичками - только этот вариант более, чем в два раза быстрее.
Почему так ??

**PS:Изменение порядка вариантов на результат не влияет! То есть я переставлял 5ый цикл в самое начало - результат тот же.**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    size_t num = 9999999;


    //-----------------Наполнение вектора произвольными значениями--------

    std::vector<size_t>my_vector_rand;
    my_vector_rand.resize(num);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        my_vector_rand[i] = rand() % 100;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    int clock1;
    int clock2;





    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter1 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));

    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter1[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_without_all:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter1[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------






    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter2 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));

    memset(my_sizet_pionter2, 0, num * sizeof(size_t));
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter2[num - 1] << std::endl;     //Нужен, чтобы компилятор не оптимизировал вышестоящий memset.


    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter2[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_memset_zero:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter2[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------




    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter3 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));

    memset(my_sizet_pionter3, 1, num * sizeof(size_t));
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter3[num - 1] << std::endl;     //Нужен, чтобы компилятор не оптимизировал вышестоящий memset.

    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter3[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_memset_one:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter3[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------






    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter4 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));


    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        my_sizet_pionter4[i] = 0;
    }
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter4[num - 1] << std::endl;     //Нужен, чтобы компилятор не оптимизировал вышестоящий цикл.



    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter4[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_cycle_zero:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter4[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------





    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter5 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));


    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        my_sizet_pionter5[i] = 1;
    }
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter5[num - 1] << std::endl;     //Нужен, чтобы компилятор не оптимизировал вышестоящий цикл.


    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter5[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_cycle_one:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter5[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Дизассемблированный код memset и цикла установки 0 или 1:

```
    memset(my_sizet_pionter2, 0, num * sizeof(size_t));
    00007FF798DC5A36  mov         rax,qword ptr [num]  
    00007FF798DC5A3A  shl         rax,3  
    00007FF798DC5A3E  mov         r8,rax  
    00007FF798DC5A41  xor         edx,edx  
    00007FF798DC5A43  mov         rcx,qword ptr [my_sizet_pionter2]  
    00007FF798DC5A4A  call        memset (07FF798DC1460h)  
    
    
    memset(my_sizet_pionter3, 1, num * sizeof(size_t));
    00007FF798DC5B80  mov         rax,qword ptr [num]  
    00007FF798DC5B84  shl         rax,3  
    00007FF798DC5B88  mov         r8,rax  
    00007FF798DC5B8B  mov         edx,1  
    00007FF798DC5B90  mov         rcx,qword ptr [my_sizet_pionter3]  
    00007FF798DC5B97  call        memset (07FF798DC1460h)  
    



    
           for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
00007FF798DC5CCD  mov         qword ptr [rbp+1A8h],0  
00007FF798DC5CD8  jmp         main+46Bh (07FF798DC5CEBh)  
00007FF798DC5CDA  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+1A8h]  
00007FF798DC5CE1  inc         rax  
00007FF798DC5CE4  mov         qword ptr [rbp+1A8h],rax  
00007FF798DC5CEB  mov         rax,qword ptr [num]  
00007FF798DC5CEF  cmp         qword ptr [rbp+1A8h],rax  
00007FF798DC5CF6  jae         main+490h (07FF798DC5D10h)  
    {
        my_sizet_pionter4[i] = 0;
00007FF798DC5CF8  mov         rax,qword ptr [my_sizet_pionter4]  
00007FF798DC5CFF  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+1A8h]  
00007FF798DC5D06  mov         qword ptr [rax+rcx*8],0  
    }
    
    



    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
00007FF798DC5E41  mov         qword ptr [rbp+208h],0  
00007FF798DC5E4C  jmp         main+5DFh (07FF798DC5E5Fh)  
00007FF798DC5E4E  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+208h]  
00007FF798DC5E55  inc         rax  
00007FF798DC5E58  mov         qword ptr [rbp+208h],rax  
00007FF798DC5E5F  mov         rax,qword ptr [num]  
00007FF798DC5E63  cmp         qword ptr [rbp+208h],rax  
00007FF798DC5E6A  jae         main+604h (07FF798DC5E84h)  
    {
        my_sizet_pionter5[i] = 1;
00007FF798DC5E6C  mov         rax,qword ptr [my_sizet_pionter5]  
00007FF798DC5E73  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+208h]  
00007FF798DC5E7A  mov         qword ptr [rax+rcx*8],1  
    }
```

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ:**

Если после каждого memset`а, который заполняет выделенную память 1 или 0.

И если после цикла, который заполняет выделенную память 0 - добавить вот эти строки:

```
size_t summ_memset_0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    summ_memset_0 = summ_memset_0 + my_sizet_pionter2[i];
}
std::cout << summ_memset_0 << std::endl;
```

То теперь время выполнения у всех вариантов кроме 1-го, у которого память не инициализировалась - время выполнения становится одинаковым.

1: 31 мс

2: 11 мс

3: 12 мс

4: 13 мс

5: 12 мс

То есть не точно, но вероятно компилятор, все таки оптимизировал код, и похоже выбрасывал инициализацию выделенной памяти через memset и через цикл.
Но инициализацию выделенной памяти через цикл 1-ками - почему то оставлял.

Вот итоговый код:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{

    size_t num = 9999999;


    //-----------------Filling a vector random values--------

    std::vector<size_t>my_vector_rand;
    my_vector_rand.resize(num);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        my_vector_rand[i] = rand() % 100;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    int clock1;
    int clock2;



    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter1 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));

    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter1[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_without_all:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter1[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------






    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter2 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));

    memset(my_sizet_pionter2, 0, num * sizeof(size_t));
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter2[num - 1] << std::endl;     //It is necessary that the compiler does not optimize memset. it didn't help.


    size_t summ_memset_0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        summ_memset_0 = summ_memset_0 + my_sizet_pionter2[i];
    }
    std::cout << summ_memset_0 << std::endl;     //It is necessary that the compiler does not optimize memset. It works.



    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter2[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_memset_zero:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter2[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------




    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter3 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));

    memset(my_sizet_pionter3, 1, num * sizeof(size_t));
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter3[num - 1] << std::endl;     //It is necessary that the compiler does not optimize memset. it didn't help.



    size_t summ_memset_1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        summ_memset_1 = summ_memset_1 + my_sizet_pionter3[i];
    }
    std::cout << summ_memset_1 << std::endl;     //It is necessary that the compiler does not optimize memset. It works.



    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter3[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_memset_one:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter3[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------






    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter4 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));


    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        my_sizet_pionter4[i] = 0;
    }
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter4[num - 1] << std::endl;     //It is necessary that the compiler does not optimize cycle. it didn't help.



    size_t summ_loop_0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        summ_loop_0 = summ_loop_0 + my_sizet_pionter4[i];
    }
    std::cout << summ_loop_0 << std::endl;     //It is necessary that the compiler does not optimize memset. It works.




    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter4[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_cycle_zero:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter4[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------





    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    size_t* my_sizet_pionter5 = (size_t*)malloc(num * sizeof(size_t));


    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        my_sizet_pionter5[i] = 1;
    }
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter5[num - 1] << std::endl;     //It is necessary that the compiler does not optimize cycle.


    clock1 = clock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        memcpy(&my_sizet_pionter5[i], &my_vector_rand[i], sizeof(size_t));
    }
    clock2 = clock();
    std::cout << "time_memcpy_cycle_one:" << clock2 - clock1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_sizet_pionter5[num - 1] << std::endl;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

Comment: Что-то оно у вас не компилируется, надо напильником допиливать... А после допилки никаких особых отличий: https://ideone.com/cLkzTC Покажите, как *воспроизвести* ваш результат.

Comment: @Harry, прошу прощения, исправил. Там у меня ошибочка в двух местах была - это замена my_vector_int  на my_vector_rand. И в последнем 5ом цикле - я инициализирую нулем, а надо единичкой. Все исправил.

Comment: Ось какая???????

Comment: Все равно все в близких пределах  — https://ideone.com/OQXSbJ

Comment: @Harry, значит это особенность визуал студии.

Comment: @avp, windows10. Влияет ?

Comment: @Harry, попробывал на другом процессоре, но скомпилированный той же VS2019 - результат тот же. 5-ый цикл в 2,5 раза быстрее.

Comment: @Optimus1, изменил свой ответ

Answer (score 4):

Хороший вопрос. Сразу скажу, что достоверного ответа у меня нет.

Похоже тут дело не только в оптимизациях компилятора, а в системе (ОС + реализация malloc).

Я откомпилировал `g++ -O3 ttt.cpp` и позапускал вот в такой системе

```
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ uname -a
Linux avp-xubu2 5.4.0-84-generic #94-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 26 20:27:37 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ g++ --vers
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ grep CPU /proc/cpuinfo | head -1
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz
avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$
```

(сам линукс установлен на VirtualBox под Windows7)

Немного модифицировал программу.

Добавил вызов функции `void dummy (size_t *x) {}`, которая компилируется раздельно, перед и после циклов копирования вектора в динамически получаемые массивы для того, чтобы гарантировано заставить компилятор всегда генерить код для инициализации массива и копирования вектора.

Также добавил измерение полного времени каждого теста (в миллисекундах), начиная с malloc и заканчивая концом копирования вектора.

Поскольку измеряемое время меняется от запуска к запуску в ощутимых пределах, я сделал внешнюю программу, которая запускает в цикле данную программу и считает среднее время выполнения каждого теста.

Получились вот такие результаты:

```
  .........
time_memcpy_cycle_zero:45  46
time_memcpy_cycle_one:15  54

time_memcpy_without_all:43  43
time_memcpy_memset_zero:43  43
time_memcpy_memset_one:15  46
time_memcpy_cycle_zero:38  38
time_memcpy_cycle_one:16  54

time_memcpy_without_all:41  41
time_memcpy_memset_zero:37  37
time_memcpy_memset_one:15  51
time_memcpy_cycle_zero:38  38
time_memcpy_cycle_one:17  47

time_memcpy_without_all:39  39
time_memcpy_memset_zero:40  40
time_memcpy_memset_one:23  59
time_memcpy_cycle_zero:47  47
time_memcpy_cycle_one:16  48
--- avg for 30 loops total msec ---
time_memcpy_without_all  38
time_memcpy_memset_zero  40
time_memcpy_memset_one   51
time_memcpy_cycle_zero   40
time_memcpy_cycle_one    49

avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$
```

(тут первое число это время копирования вектора, а второе -- общее время теста, вместе с malloc)

Т.е. мы видим, что общее время тестов без инициализации динамического массива и с инициализацией его нулями составляет порядка 40 мсек, а время выполнения тестов с инициализацией такого же массива единичками существенно больше (порядка 50 мсек).

Анализ ассемблерного кода показал:

- во всех тестах при копировании элементов вектора  компилятор распознает функцию memcpy и заменяет ее на эквивалентный цикл (копируя по 8 байт за итерацию)

  ```
    movq    (%rsp), %rcx
    movq    %rax, %r12
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
  .L30:
    movq    (%rcx,%rax,8), %rdx
    movq    %rdx, 0(%rbp,%rax,8)
    addq    $1, %rax
    cmpq    $9999999, %rax
    jne .L30
  ```
- в тестах с обнулением массива компилятор меняет malloc на calloc и выбрасывает как memset (в первом случае), так и обнуление в цикле (во втором).

***Собственно, теперь надо понять, почему тесты с обнулением работают с той же скоростью, что и без него, а тесты с инициализацией не нулем на 25% дольше?***

Вероятно (как уже указал в своем ответе @Ariox) здесь имеет место следующий сценарий, основанный на том, что современная ОС **при первом обращении к выделенной странице памяти обнуляет ее** (в целях безопасности).

malloc/calloc при запросе на большой (мы запрашиваем 76 Mбайт для каждого массива) объем памяти выполняют системный вызов mmap, т.е. каждый раз мы получаем набор виртуальных страниц, которые будут привязаны к физическим  при первом обращении. При этом связывании ОС  обнуляет страницу памяти (*ядро будет проводить обнуление в рамках текущего процесса, затраченное на это время будет засчитано ему*)  и очевидно, что  malloc и calloc в таком случае работают одинаково. **Вот тут и тратится одинаковое время на инициализацию массива** как в тесте без его прописывания, так и в тестах с его инициализацией нулями.

Очевидно, что **это же обнуление** имеет место и перед прописыванием массива единичкой, т.е. в этих 2-х тестах выполняется лишняя, не нужная нам работа.

Пожалуй, все.

Думаю, что предыдущие версии  данного ответа ("прогрев" с изменением величины preload и кэширования таблиц MMU) можно считать ошибочными и я их из текста удаляю.
(впрочем, желающие могут прочесть их, посмотрев историю редактирования)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но прикол в том, что если 5ы цикл поставить в самое начало, то результат тот же. То есть по идее, если был "прогрев", то перестановка 5го варианта в самое начало должно было бы изменить результат, но он не меняется.

Comment: @Optimus1, спасибо. Вечером попробую еще поиграться с разными вариантами и подумать.

Comment: если интересно будет прочитайте "дополнение" в моем основном сообщении. Похоже дело было в компиляторе и его оптимизации кода.

Comment: @Optimus1, отлично, приму к сведению вашу информацию, когда буду сам разбираться.

Answer (score 2):

Вставил ваш изначальный код в godbolt.org с msvc 2019. Все пять циклов были заменены на идентичный код:

```
    call    malloc
    mov     rsi, rax
    xor     edx, edx
    lea     rcx, OFFSET FLAT:std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > std::cout ; std::cout
    call    std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > & std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(unsigned __int64) ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<
    mov     rcx, rax
    call    std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > & std::endl<char,std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > &) ; std::endl<char,std::char_traits<char> >
    call    clock
    mov     ebx, eax
    mov     r8d, 79999992                   ; 04c4b3f8H
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR my_vector_rand$[rsp]
    mov     rcx, rsi
    call    memcpy
    call    clock
```

Никаких лишних операций тут нет, массив обрабатывается только в memcpy.

Т.е. как минимум, ваши предположения о причинах происходящего неверны. Также вероятно, что вы не включили нормальную оптимизацию, или установили какие-то дополнительные флаги компилятора, искажающие результат.

UPD:
Не заметил, во всех циклах оптимизирован memset, но в последней реализации что-то похожее на инициализацию перед измерением времени осталось, а удаление memset в итоге почему-то ухудшает производительность.

Перезагрузился в винду и собрал у себя: наблюдается поведение из вопроса. Лечится заменой

```
size_t num = 99999999;
```

на

```
size_t num = std::stoi("99999999"); // или другая реализация черного ящика
```

После избавления от константы time_memcpy_without_all работает медленнее остальных. Это либо промахи кэша (что сомнительно, т.к. на больших массивах тоже проявляется), либо инициализация таблиц виртуальной памяти - для больших массивов windows вроде бы не выделяет физическую память непосредственно в malloc, в выделяет виртуальную, которая инициализируемый при первом обращении. Но могу ошибаться.

Comment: не сочтите за наглость, но вставьте его не в godbolt.org , а ИМЕННО в VS2019 и только потом пишите, что мои или чьи либо еще предположения не верны. Никакие дополнительные флаги компилятора я не устанавливал. Оптимизация стандартная для VS - 02 - так же не измена. Это вы вставили в  godbolt.org, про который я ничего не писал, поэтому как минимум Ваше предположение не верно.

Comment: @Optimus1 , godbolt - это просто сайт, позволяющий скомпилировать при помощи VS2019 (или другим компилятором) и посмотреть ассемблер. Нет никакой разницы между его выводом и прямым использованием VS2019 . Разве что могут не совпасть версии. Можете сами посмотреть вывод: https://godbolt.org/z/K8GG4Psoe

Comment: я Вам верю про godbolt, но еще я больше верю своим глазам. Если у Вас все таки есть возможность запустить этот код именно в VS2019 на винде, то попробуйте. Или иначе, как тогда это объяснить ?

Comment: @Ariox, с большой вероятностью вы правы в своем выводе, что **все дело в выделении и отложенной инициализации памяти**, но это маскируется в программе ТС тем, что время при прописывании памяти через memset не учитывается. Я игрался в linux с этой программой, разными уровнями оптимизации и разглядыванием ассемблерного кода и пожалуй, пришел к такому же выводу. Особенно интересным был случай, когда оптимизатор распознает обнуление и вместо malloc вызывает calloc (после чего я вижу такое же большое время, как и без инициализации)

Comment: @avp, еще одно наблюдение, если за место my_vector_rand[i] в цикле memcpy- поставить случайный порядок копирования --> my_vector_rand[my_vector_rand[i]], то все циклы работают с одинаковым временем.